# Postgresql function returning setof empty

Tags: postgresql

I have a function in `PostgreSQL` that should return a custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE report_band_type AS ( 
t_id_band INTEGER,
t_num_instruments INTEGER, 
t_num_members_alive INTEGER, 
t_longest_album_title VARCHAR(255), 
t_num_short_songs INTEGER
);
```

The function works perfect except the return which is empty:

```
,,,,
```

The function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ubd_20211.update_report_band(p_name VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS SETOF ubd_20211.report_band_type
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $$
DECLARE 

band_exists boolean;
id_band_result integer;
band_exists_report boolean;
result_return ubd_20211.report_band_type;
BEGIN 


    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ubd_20211.band
    WHERE LOWER(name) = LOWER(p_name)) INTO band_exists;
    RAISE NOTICE 'p_name és %', p_name; 

    IF band_exists THEN 
        SELECT id_band FROM ubd_20211.band
        WHERE LOWER(name) = LOWER(p_name) INTO id_band_result;
        
        SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ubd_20211.REPORT_BAND 
        WHERE id_band = id_band_result) INTO band_exists_report;            
            
        IF band_exists_report THEN
            UPDATE ubd_20211.REPORT_BAND 
            SET num_instruments =auxiliar.num_instruments, 
            num_members_alive =auxiliar.num_members_alive,
            longest_album_title =auxiliar.title,
            num_short_songs = auxiliar.num_short_songs
            FROM (SELECT B.id_band, COUNT(MEM.instrument) AS num_instruments, COUNT(MUS.name) AS num_members_alive, AL.title, COUNT(S.duration) AS num_short_songs                  
                FROM ubd_20211.BAND AS B
                INNER JOIN ubd_20211.MEMBER AS MEM ON B.id_band = MEM.id_band 
                INNER JOIN ubd_20211.MUSICIAN AS MUS ON MEM.id_musician = MUS.id_musician 
                INNER JOIN ubd_20211.ALBUM AS AL ON B.id_band = AL.id_band 
                INNER JOIN ubd_20211.SONG AS S ON AL.id_album = S.id_album 
                WHERE B.id_band = id_band_result AND S.duration < '00:3:00' AND MUS.death is NULL 
                                                    AND AL.title = (SELECT title FROM ubd_20211.BAND AS B2
                                                                         INNER JOIN ubd_20211.ALBUM AS AL2 ON B2.id_band = AL2.id_band
                                                                         WHERE B2.id_band = B.id_band
                                                                         ORDER BY LENGTH(AL2.title) DESC LIMIT 1)               

                GROUP BY 1,4) AS auxiliar 
            WHERE REPORT_BAND.id_band = auxiliar.id_band;
            
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO ubd_20211.REPORT_BAND (id_band, num_instruments, num_members_alive, longest_album_title, num_short_songs) 
            SELECT B.id_band, COUNT(MEM.instrument) AS num_instruments, COUNT(MUS.name) AS num_members_alive, AL.title, COUNT(S.duration) AS num_short_songs                    
            FROM ubd_20211.BAND AS B
            INNER JOIN ubd_20211.MEMBER AS MEM ON B.id_band = MEM.id_band 
            INNER JOIN ubd_20211.MUSICIAN AS MUS ON MEM.id_musician = MUS.id_musician 
            INNER JOIN ubd_20211.ALBUM AS AL ON B.id_band = AL.id_band 
            INNER JOIN ubd_20211.SONG AS S ON AL.id_album = S.id_album 
            WHERE B.id_band = id_band_result AND S.duration < '00:3:00' AND MUS.death is NULL AND AL.title = (SELECT title FROM ubd_20211.BAND AS B2
                                                             INNER JOIN ubd_20211.ALBUM AS AL2 ON B2.id_band = AL2.id_band
                                                             WHERE B2.id_band = B.id_band
                                                             ORDER BY LENGTH(AL2.title) DESC LIMIT 1)               
                                                                                                                     
            GROUP BY 1,4;
        
        END IF;
        SELECT B.id_band, COUNT(MEM.instrument) AS num_instruments, COUNT(MUS.name) AS num_members_alive, AL.title, COUNT(S.duration) AS num_short_songs                    
                INTO result_return
                FROM ubd_20211.BAND AS B
                INNER JOIN ubd_20211.MEMBER AS MEM ON B.id_band = MEM.id_band 
                INNER JOIN ubd_20211.MUSICIAN AS MUS ON MEM.id_musician = MUS.id_musician 
                INNER JOIN ubd_20211.ALBUM AS AL ON B.id_band = AL.id_band 
                INNER JOIN ubd_20211.SONG AS S ON AL.id_album = S.id_album 
                WHERE B.id_band = id_band_result AND S.duration < '00:3:00' AND MUS.death is NULL 
                                                    AND AL.title = (SELECT title FROM ubd_20211.BAND AS B2
                                                                         INNER JOIN ubd_20211.ALBUM AS AL2 ON B2.id_band = AL2.id_band
                                                                         WHERE B2.id_band = B.id_band
                                                                         ORDER BY LENGTH(AL2.title) DESC LIMIT 1)               

                GROUP BY 1,4;
    
    ELSE 
        RAISE NOTICE 'Not exists';
    END IF;
RETURN NEXT result_return;
END;
$$
```

Probably the problem is:

```
RETURN NEXT result_return;
```

Which returns an empty NEXT, and this makes sense, but when I do: `RETURN result_return`
I get this error(translated) when creating the function:

```
can't have a parameter in  a function that returns a setof
```

How can I do the return of the specific type plus the insert or update operations?

Comment: Why don't you simply `RETURN (SELECT …)`?

Comment: @Bergi It says RETURN can't have a parameter in a function that returns a setof. Use Return next or return query.

Comment: Ah right I messed up the syntax, [it needs to be `RETURN QUERY SELECT …;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

Comment: yes, i imagine you mean that later and i tried and working. Thanks!